# Changing values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
<span class="label-info">3</span>
```

I have the following jquery

```
var replaceit = $(this).closest(':has(.label-info)').find('.label-info').text();
```

The value of the variable is always a single whole number but will not always be 3:

```
ie: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
```

I have tried this numerous ways and cannot get the value to change. My latest attempt was:

```
return $(this).closest(':has(.label-info)').html().replace(replaceit, (replaceit - 1));
```

My end result, is to subtract 1 from whatever the current value of "lable-info" is, and switch it with this new result. So a new span based on the value of 3 would become.

```
<span class="label-info">2</span>
```

How do I achieve this?

**Updated Code for more clarity**

html:

```
<div>
<span class="lable-info">3</span>
</div>

<div>
   <a class="accept_friend">accept</a>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
    $(document).on("click", "a.accept_friend", function() { 
        var checkValue = $(this).closest(':has(.name)').find('.name').text();
        var removeit = $(this).closest(':has(.item)').find('.item').fadeOut();
        var replaceit = $(this).closest(':has(.label-info)').find('.label-info').text();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/includes/accept_friend.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {checkValue},
            success:function(data){
            return removeit;
            $("a.remove_pending").text(function () {
            return ('.label-info').html().replace(replacei, replaceit); 
        });
    }
```

**Notes:**

I am not using id. I am using class. There are multiple classes with the same name. So I have to call by closest.

Comment: What is the issue you are currently facing with this code?

Comment: Can you add a bit more code for a clear view. because the `$(this)` represents what.

Comment: What scope are you in, is that the global `this` being the window? Also why not just do `$('.label-info').text()`?

Comment: @Sasikumar give me two minutes please.

Comment: I don't see your `<span class="lable-info">` getting closed instead you have closed `</a>`

Comment: that was just a typo in my cut and paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting a value from a span, subtracting it by 1 and updating the span(using jQuery):

**HTML**

```
<span class="label-info">3</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
var n  = $(".label-info").text(),
    n2 = n - 1;
$(".label-info").text(n2);
```

Hope it helps a bit

Comment: Or: `$(".label-info").text(+$(".label-info").text()-1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Please try below code

```
var currentVal = $(this).closest(':has(.label-info)').html();

var newValue = parseInt(currentVal - 1);

return newValue;
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to store the value as a data attribute too,  rather than accessing the html()  in case you want to add any display logic to be number (e.g. An ordinal number 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc),  as parseInt will fail.

Comment: @doublesidestickytape it is clearly written that *The value of the variable is always a single whole number* not an `ordinal number (1st, 2nd etc)`

Comment: I don't need the parseInt() for this to work, the problem is actually switching the values.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
var replaceit = $(this).closest(':has(.label-info)').text();
$(this).closest(':has(.label-info)').text(replaceit-1);
```

Example fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nzdtnoas/

Comment: this seems to replace the value, but its not simply replacing the value of the .label-info, its placing all content in the parent of .label-info. so if <div><a></a><div></div><span class="label-info">2</span></div> is becoming <div><span class="label-info">1</span></div> and its dropping the other div and a.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.text( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to changing text of element to another string.

```js
$(".label-info").text(function(i, text){
    return text - 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="label-info">3</span>
```

Comment: every time I try this, it returns NAN

Comment: @Bruce Maybe text of target element isn't number.

Comment: nope already used alert(replaceit); to ensure it is a number.

Comment: @Bruce You don't understanded the function. `.text( function )` change text of selected element (`$(".label-info")`).

Comment: I do understand it, it just didn't work in this situation for my usage, nor did the example below, but the one I marked did

Comment: @Bruce You used `.text()` after `return`. code after return doesn't execute.

Comment: I tried your code, directly after the assignment of my variables, before the execution of any returns, as was the case with the other code I commented on that I couldn't get to work, it removes all the contents not just the text AND it returned NAN not a number.

Comment: @Brace I don't know what is problem or how you use the code, but there is no diffrence between my code and @ codelock code.

Comment: well I NOW know what the difference is, as I just learned. I was actually improperly using the code $(this).closest(':has(.label-info)').find('.label-info').text() instead of $(this).closest('.label-info').text(). If I use the correct code, ALL answers on this page work.